# Two FileUpload components in the same form getting updated at the same time when I choose ONE component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have two fileuploads in the same form I am using different ids for them also.The problem is when I use any one upload component and choose and delect the file.Both components are getting updated.I am giving the components one by one.
Upload1:

```
<p:growl id="messages" showSummary="true" showDetail="true" />
                    <p:fileUpload id="upload2" fileUploadListener="#{editBean.relatedFileEditUpload}"
                        rendered="#{editBean.uploadFileRender}"
                        process="studyPlanEditForm:relatedFileType"
                        update="studyPlanEditForm:messages studyPlanEditForm:relatedFileType">
                    </p:fileUpload>
```

fileupload2:

```
<p:column
                    style="padding-bottom: 10px;background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EDEDED;width:30px;">
                    <p:growl id="messages1" showSummary="true" showDetail="true" />
                    <p:fileUpload  id="upload1" fileUploadListener="#{editBean.editFileUpload}" 
                        process="studyPlanEditForm:displayname1"
                        update=":studyPlanEditForm">
                    </p:fileUpload>
                </p:column>
```

When I choose any one upload and browse and select a file both components are showing the file name.Please help.

Comment: Hi The probem is coming for both the components.

Comment: not sure what is default mode of `fileUpload` but try using `mode="advanced" auto="true"` cause it seems that you are using the basic mode which submit the entire form

Comment: I tried but not working .I am using it as a advanced upload.As per the primefaces3 user manual "Multiple advanced uploaders in same form is not supported at the moment.". Perhaps that could be the reason.

Comment: so split forms , one for table and the other one for the other file upload...